# some OSX block the socket call to port 80, until a complete HTTP Request

Tags: c, macos, sockets

some osx will block my socket call on port 80, until I write a complete HTTP request.
How to disable this feature or bug ?

here is a simple code in c, it writes data through port 80;

```
int main() {
    int port = 80;
    char *content = "hello world";
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == 0) {
        printf("connect ok\n");
        write(fd, content, strlen(content));
    } else {
        printf("connect fail\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I run this code in several macs with no process listening on the port 80.
In some macs, it will still print "connect ok" but nothing show on tcpdump's screen.

I tried with different params, and realized OSX treat the data through port 80 as HTTP data.
It will "hold" my system calls, unless my data contains string "HTTP/" and "\r\n\r\n".
It does the same trick in port 8080.

Here is the test result in the macs that the "feature" exists.
(no server is listening on port 80 nor 8080)

```
|port      |    content                  | binary output |          tcpdump output      |
|:--------:|:---------------------------:|:-------------:|:-----------------------------|
| 80/8080  |    hello                    | connect ok    |             nothing          |
| 80/8080  |GET HTTP/1.1 \r\n\r\n        | connect ok    |client send syn packet, server reply with reset packet|
| 12345    |    any data                 | connect fail  |syn and reset packet          |
| 80/8080  |lkfjHTTP/dsfkj\r\n\r\na.dkjfk| connect ok    |syn and reset packet          |
```

I guess this is a built-in strategy to improve the HTTP client performance.But I transfer binary data with spdy protocol on port 80, How can I disable this feature?

I googled several days, but haven't found anything yet.

I can't be the first one who transfer non-HTTP protocol on port 80 in OSX :(

Comment: I suspect some kind of firewall feature.

Comment: Or maybe it's part of parental control, it has to check the web site name.

Comment: @Barmar It seems reasonable! but I just checked the settings, firewall is turned off.

Comment: @trojanfoe There is no server listening on port 80, so the "connect" call should return -1, binary output should be "connect fail", other than "connect ok".

Comment: Tests 2 and 4 show that something is listening on port 80 and test 3 shows what happens when nothing is listening on a port.

Comment: This sounds like an application level firewall (like little snitch) interfering with normal network operations. When you are faced with an anomaly you have to follow a methodical troubleshooting process. In this case, track down all the differences between the working and non-working system (OS, applications, configuration, account).

Comment: @Petesh sounds reasonable. I tried to use dtruss but can't found anything. Is there any tool in OSX can detect the system call?

Comment: dtruss stops at the application<->kernel interface, most app firewalls operate inside the kernel. Vagrant allows port forwarding to VMs (there may be ports diverted; check ipfw on pre-mavericks, pfctl on mavericks - I don't know how it does it). `netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep 80` would show if something is listening on 80 or 8080. Use `lsof -n | grep LISTEN` to find things listening on `http(80)/http-alt(8080)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found `"local acwebsecagent[156]: Connection : HTTP/ *NOT* FOUND. CMode : 0 TMode : 0
"` log in /var/log/system.log when connecting to port 80 and 8080

acwebsecagent is Cisco AnyConnect Web security module, after I uninstall the stupid security module, It finally works.

To uninstall it. run `sudo /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/websecurity_uninstall.sh`

related links: http://blog.felipe-alfaro.com/2014/02/10/cisco-anyconnect-web-security-module-acwebsecagent-in-mac-os-x/
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect30/administration/guide/anyconnectadmin30/ac06websecurity.html#pgfId-1065063

Comment: I just ran in to an issue with the exact same symptoms.  After tracking it down to `connect()` system calls on port 80 I found this article.  For me the trouble process was SophosWebIntelligence, and after restarting it everything  is quick again!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you think the results you get are a problem.  When you connect to a server you have to conform to the network protocol that the server provides.  In the case of HTTP that means sending a complete HTTP Request and in return you will get an HTTP Response.

You state that nothing is listening on port 80, however tests 2 and 4 show that something is (and that will be Apache, no doubt).

I do not understand why `tcpdump` displays nothing in the first case, however that appears to contradict the other results you get, so it's possibly an anomaly, so please retry your test.

Comment: no server is listening on port 80, so "connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server))" should return -1, other than 0.

Comment: tcpdump capture tcp packet, only if the data I wrote contains string "HTTP/" and "\r\n\r\n".

Comment: @simpx Have you stopped Apache then, as I believe it runs as default?

Comment: I'm sure there is no process listening on port 80. That's where the problem lies. the "connect" call tells me I have connected to server. but the tcpdump tells me, my connection is reseted because there is no server process

Comment: compare the binary output and tcpdump output in Case 2 and 4, it is really confused

Comment: @simpx Go to the command prompt and type `telnet 80` and start typing.

Comment: I have tried "telnet" and "nc". telnet will succeed immediately. but tcpdump shows nothing again.

Comment: @simpx OK, so we know that something is listening on port 80.  `netstat -a` should reveal what that process is...

Comment: 1. there is no port 80 in netstat -a 2. if there is server listening port 80, tcpdump will capture the tcp packet 3. I reproduce this problem in several macs..

Answer (score -1):

I don't think "to improve the HTTP client performance" is the reason using TCP port 80 for other protocols than HTTP is discouraged.

According to the  Privilege Port declaration by W3C,(http://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html)

80 is the normal port for W3 servers. You may consider switching for a port above 1024 to run other protocols.

By the way, Apache Tomcat usually set its default HTTP request listening port to 8080.

Comment: thank you.But I'm sure there is no process listening on 80 or 8080

Comment: @simpx You have just conducted a test (using `telnet`) that demonstrates that there is a process listening on port 80!